# Power of a test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, statistical-power

I need help with the exercise below:

To investigate the effect of a new vaccine, 150 out of 300 sick animals were given the vaccine and the remaining 150 were given nothing. After a while, 10 of those who were given the vaccine and 30 who were not given the vaccine died. In this case, assuming $\alpha=0.05$ can we say that the vaccine decreases the proportion of death? In addition what would the power of the test be?

I stated the hypothesis as follows:

$H_0: P_{vaccine}=P_{No-vaccine}$

$H_1: P_{vaccine} < P_{No-vaccine} $

What formula should I use for the test statistics?

Comment: What would justify your assumption that the vaccine could not possibly do any harm?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.Can you be more clear?

Comment: Consider your alternative hypothesis: what does it say?

Comment: It says the vaccine decreases the proportion of death, doesn't it?

Comment: In other words, H0 and H1 are supposed to be exhaustive and mutually exclusive. In the current form, the possibility that $P_{v+} > P_{v-}$ is not accounted for.